# How to display all database queries made by Wordpress with ajax?

Tags: mysql, ajax, database, wordpress

I am using $wpdb->queries to show all running queries made by wordpress. This working fine when using simple php function but it's not showing same results when call same function with ajax. eg: if my simple php function showing results 15 but my ajax call function will show only 5 queries.

Comment: you might be able to see it all, with this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `define('SAVEQUERIES', true)` to your configuration file, you can then list all the queries made for the current page by adding the following to your theme.

You can try like this:

```
if (current_user_can('administrator')){
    global $wpdb;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wpdb->queries);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

See the documentation for more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Save_queries_for_analysis

Comment: already using same, but it's not showing same results when run with ajax.